# HTML5 Video - data coming from database

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, webforms, html5-video, asp.net-4.0

Customers are fun - coming up with new requirements all the time....

OK, so I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms application where the customer is able to upload files (like PDF's or Excel documents) and those are being stored in SQL Server inside a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column. Works like a charm.

Now they dreamed up a new requirement: they would like to also be able to upload videos (like *.wmv, *.mp4 etc.). Contrary to the documents that just get downloaded to the customer's hard disk when requested, for the videos, they would like to have them played on my Webforms application.

After a bit of research, it would seem the HTML5 `<video>` tag would be the most efficient way to go. But all the samples I'm seeing out there are using file-based URL's to get the video - but I cannot seem to find any mention of how to supply the video data from a **stream**.

Do I really need to store my videos from my SQL Server database into a temporary file on disk to play them in my Webforms application? Or is there a nifty way to connect a .NET stream (`MemoryStream`) to a HTML5 `<video>` element to play the video on screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply buffer the data via a special page you make, for example: `getvideo.aspx?videoid=nnn` using the page as a stream proxy.

In the page you stream the data as any file, to the client setting the header mime type to video/mp4 and making sure it's in 8-bit binary format.

Then you simply set the page as video source to the element:

**HTML:**

```
<video width=640 height=320 autoplay controls>
    <source src="getvideo.aspx?videoid=123&type=mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="getvideo.aspx?videoid=123&type=ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Sorry, no video support in the browser you're using.
</video>
```

Note that not all browsers supports the MP4 file format. You might need to consider allowing a fallback format such as OGG and WEBM.

Comment: Thanks - can you elaborate a bit on the first two paragraphs? They totally sound greek to me :-) Do you have a page / blog post / article that shows (in code) how to actually do this? (I've seen approaches with `.ashx` handlers, which supposedly stream back the data - unfortunately, all the samples I have found so far really don't work in the end - no video appears on the page....)

Comment: @marc_s I am unfortunately short on both blog and .net page :( Sorry about that. I will look to see if I can get around that or find examples. In principle when you query the SQL server you just push the data that is returned directly to output stream from inside that page (just send the headers first before running the query of course).

Comment: For the sample that serves byte stream (of video) from arbitrary source like DB blob: http://www.martin-brennan.com/aha-1-ashx-video-streaming/ .  Nice that he shows how to tell Chrome video player the video can seek.